# How to associate multiple subnet to route table?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pulumi

I am trying to connect multiple subnets to the same publicRoutetable, I don't know if I am doing it right, I am very new to Pulumi and AWS. Please let me know how to do that.

I am getting an error:

```
error: Duplicate resource URN 'urn:pulumi:Dev::Iac_pulumi::aws:ec2/routeTableAssociation:RouteTableAssociation::publicRouteTableAssociationCalling 'toString' on an 'Output\<T\>' is not supported.
This is because the value of an 'Output' is asynchronous.

To get the value of an Output\<T\> as an Output\<String\> consider either:
1: applyValue(v -\> String.format("prefix%ssuffix", v))
2: Output.format("prefix%ssuffix", o)
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
for (Subnet publicSubnet : publicSubnets) {
    new RouteTableAssociation("publicRouteTableAssociation" + publicSubnet.id(), RouteTableAssociationArgs.builder()
            .routeTableId(publicRouteTable.id())
            .subnetId(publicSubnet.id())
            .build());
}
```